# Как добавить несколько файлов с функцией main в одном проекте в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

У меня есть несколько программ состоящих из одного C++ файла, с функцией main. Хочется сделать так, чтобы в одном проекте было несколько файлов с функцией main и можно было как-то переключаться между тем какая из этих программ исполняется и компилируется в настоящий момент. Может есть способ написать какой-нибудь .h скрипт или что-то такое.

Comment: Можно написать функцию `my_main`  в нескольких вариантах и вызывать ее из `main` по условию.

Comment: Чем не устраивает несколько проектов в одном workspace?

Comment: Да, видимо я так давно не пользовался вижуалкой, что забыл, что можно сделать проектов в одном workspace'е